# How to use a list of values in a separate file and import and use it in another script?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently using the same list of values in many of my scripts and thought it would be easier to keep one copy of this list in a separate .py script and be able to import it as necessary. This list frequently changes so it will make it easier for me to only have to go to the single file and edit the list as necessary.

```
Sites={
    "The Zoo":"123",
    "The Airport":"234",
    "The School":"345",
    "The Mall":"456"
}

list_of_sites = Sites.values()
```

Again what I am hoping to be able to do is have the Sites list contained in another file and import it. Would I have to do something like this if the file was named site_master_list.py:

```
import site_master_list
site_list = sites_master_list.sites
```

Comment: so you can just do it. `from site_master_list import  list_of_sites`. It would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `site_master_list.py` will look as follows

```
Sites={
    "The Zoo":"123",
    "The Airport":"234",
    "The School":"345",
    "The Mall":"456"
}

list_of_sites = Sites.values()
```

The other file will then be

```
from site_master_list import list_of_sites
```